# Athena scalar subquery issue

Tags: scalar-subquery

I am working on athena . 
I have a table with two columns of interest besides other columns. They are id and account architect column. Both are string type .

[image]

This is how the table looks like now .

The end product should be ;

[image]

The query that i have is : 
[image]

[image]

How should my query look like to get this end product .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem.
Note Here I am using regexp_replace to remove all special characters like (comma,],[,double quotes).

```
select array_agg(distinct id),regexp_replace(username,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']') from 
(
select split_part("sto architect",',',1) as username,id from xyz_teams
Union 
select split_part("sto architect",',',2) as username,id from xyz_teams
) temp_tbl
group by regexp_replace(username,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']')
```

Comment: thank you very much @deepak ... the query works well indeed . pardon me for my  very  stupid question  .  I added architects here   -- >  SELECT array_agg(distinct id),regexp_replace(username,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']') AS architects from ( ..... )  to reflect column name as architects . I cant figure out where to add AS id to reflect the first column name as id . it now shows as _col0 .  Thank you , your response has been very helpful .

Comment: So now after running the above code the output looks like what i mentioned above .

Comment: So now after running the above code the output looks like what i mentioned above .Because the actual data has account ids of varied lengths and also include characters as well , my final effort is to only show those account ids in the id column with a certain length say 6 and omit any length other than 6 and also any id which has any character in between other than a number .

Comment: _col0                                             architects                                          
837246,tiy-973-gjdu                    djfgf
598428,fdjrt-gjkdf-343 , urid_jf_fi     fdgdf
847392                                             rtwsz
598423,fcvghb,kcjgrd                     gndfs                                                                               this is the table output i have and i want the table to show  only let say account id which is of length 6 and nothing else .

Comment: WITH dataset AS ( SELECT id , 
SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT"architects"FROM xyz_teams),']'), '['), ',') AS architects 
FROM xyz_teams) 
SELECT array_agg(distinct id),regexp_replace(username,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']') AS architects from 
(
select split_part("sto architect",',',1) as username,id from xyz_teams where length(split_part("sto architect",',',1)) = cast (6 as integer)
Union 
select split_part("sto architect",',',2) as username,id from xyz_teams where length(split_part("sto architect",',',2)) = cast (6 as integer)) temp_tbl
group by regexp_replace(username,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']')